# Hilbert transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Let $\mathscr H$ be the Hilbert transform, that is the Fourier multiplier by $\text{sign } \xi$:
$$
(\mathscr H u)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{2iπ x\xi }(\text{sign } \xi) \hat u(\xi) d\xi.
$$
The Hilbert transform is a singular integral defined by the convolution 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0_+}\int_{\vert x-y\vert>\epsilon}\frac{u(y)}{iπ (x-y)} dy.
$$
It is a bounded (and even unitary and selfadjoint) operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, bounded on 
$L^p(\mathbb R)$ for $1<p<+\infty$,
not bounded on $L^1$ or $L^\infty$.

My question: are there some boundedness results of $\mathscr H$ from $L^p$ to $L^q$ for some values of $p,q\in (0,1)$?

Comment: I doubt there is such.

Comment: Wouldn't you get boundedness on $L^1$ by interpolation if you had such a property?